# Unable to refresh the page after download a file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, httpresponse

My current task is that I have to update a key in database,get the link to download and also refresh the page in order to update my repeater.Below is the ways i have tried and issues i have faced.

1. Javascript - Popup does not open as blocked by browser
2. In Code behind I have added the code below but what it does is the response object gets cleared and hence my previous changes made like the updated repeater and code is cleared(Check code below)
3. Redirect to another page and using session take the file url from original to other page and download it there - Issue faced is that it does not even show that page as it has response.clear

   ```
   string strURL = Session["Url"].ToString();
           WebClient req = new WebClient();
           HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
           response.Clear();
           response.ClearContent();
           response.ClearHeaders();
           response.Buffer = true;
           response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + strURL + "\"");
           byte[] data = req.DownloadData(strURL);
           if (data != null &&
               data.Length > 0)
           {
               response.BinaryWrite(data);
           }
           Session["Url"] = null;
           if (Session["DigitalDownloadURL"] != null &&
               Session["DigitalDownloadURL"].ToString() != string.Empty)
           {
               lnkbtnGoBack.PostBackUrl =  Session["DigitalDownloadURL"].ToString();
           }
   ```

How to update my repeater after clicking on download button?

Comment: That won't work. You either send a file or an updated HTML page to the client. Not both. If you want to make changes you'll have to use a client side solution.

Comment: @VDWWD like how to use client side as the main purpose to use asp.net was to hide my url and implementation and using window.open blocks my popup